# Laravel 5.7 REST api , update section error

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

`Create`,`Delete`,`Show` section is working as well. I don't know what's problem.

This is my request (when I call the `PUT` of a resource route):

```
============
Request body
============
name: John doe
detail: An insteresting detail
type: A fancy type

===============
Request Headers
===============
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer my_secret_token
```

**Error**

> "message": "No query results for model [App\Product]."

**Api\Controller**

```php
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $input = $request->all();


    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required'
    ]);


    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());       
    }


    $product->name = $input['name'];
    $product->detail = $input['detail'];
    $product->save();


    return $this->sendResponse($product->toArray(), 'Product updated successfully.');
}
```

Comment: you'll need to `find` your product before you attempt to update it.

Comment: is it like `$product = Product::findOrFail($id);` ?

Comment: I added an anwser, yes correct.

Comment: He doesn't have to find it as he inject the model as the second argument!

Comment: @Matt We don't know if it has been properly injected from the code shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Route Model Binding (as it seems), be sure to use the proper endopoint to update your resource:

```php
PUT /products/{product}
// so this means, for example:
PUT /products/3
```

Then, Laravel will automatically find a Product with the `id` of 3.

```php
public function update(Request $request, Product $product) // <-- here is injected.
{
    // the rest of your code..
}
```

The other option is to find the resource manually. If your route is like this:

```php
PUT /products/{id}
```

Find it like this if you want to manage the response easily:

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // find it
    $product = Product::find($request->get('id'));

    // check if exists
    if (! $product)
    {
        return response()->json(['errors' => 'This product does not exist, dude!'], 404);
    }

    // the rest of your code..
}
```

or like this to throw an exception:

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // find it
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->get('id'));

    // the rest of your code..
}
```

Comment: You left the comment `// <-- here is injected.` where the product is not injected.

Comment: @adam, yeah a typo, I copied the previous block. I'll update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enter in the folder of your project

```
cd /laravel/your/path_of/api_project
```

and execute the following command

```
php artisan route:list
```

and you will have a complete table that contains the names of the methods to use and their url and each methods to use (POST, GET, ...)

output example ----

```
| PUT|PATCH | api/companys/{company}|  companys.update| App\Http\Controllers\CompanysController@update|
```